# Pass variable from input to form

Tags: php

How can I pass variable from input field to form like this and is it possible?

```
<form method="POST" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?login_hint=<?= $_GET['email']?>" id= "frmTest" name = "frmTest">
   <input type="email" id="email" name="email"  />
   <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Or maybe with javascript somehow?
When user fill out that form and click on submit button I want that form redirect him to 
https://accounts.google.com/ where it will display that email and user will just enter his password

Comment: I do not see a problem in the code , have you tried and found any error?

Comment: what does this mean pass variable from input field?

Comment: It should work fine by using regular post code. Also you are missing an end-quote after the id tag. What is it you have tried, and what is your actual problem with the usual approach?

Comment: when i run this code... email field on login page of google is empty but when i write manual email on login_hint = something@gmail.com it appears on login page of google...if u know what i mean

Comment: Is your intentions to have the email that is typed into the email field to be added to the address, then JavaScript is a lot easier for this. Just have a click event that leads you to the link with the email appended at the end dynamically. Not sure if this is exactly what you desire to do, though.

Comment: this question is unclear... impossible to answer.

Comment: My itention is when user click on submit button my form redirect him to "https://accounts.google.com/ and email on that page is fill out with email from my form and user will just need to enter his password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `POST` method in your form, you can't add `GET` query parameter in your `action` attribute.

In a `POST` form these parameters in the `action` URL will be discarded. So either send your form as `GET` (`method="GET"`) and keep the query string as is, or keep it as POST and add the fields in hidden inputs like:

```
<form method="POST" action="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" id="frmTest" name="frmTest">
  <input type="hidden" name="login_hint" value="<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>" />
  <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that I see solution. You are sending data by POST method, but expect that they be in $_GET variable. Change one of methods (POST/GET) to another in Your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it to a hidden input like this:

```
  <input type=hidden name=login_hint value="<?php echo $_GET['email'] ?>" >
```